# Pass runtime size_t variable into template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a tuple and I want to do something with the type in the tuple at the passed index (in the example, print the default). Currently I have it call a function increasing a templated index until it equals the runtime index. As this method decreases performance, is there a better way?

Here is the code for the example:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using tup = std::tuple<int, std::string, double, int>;

template <size_t Index = 0>
void constexpr PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex(size_t i)
{
    if (Index == i)
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << std::tuple_element_t<Index, tup>() << "\"" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if constexpr (Index + 1 < std::tuple_size_v<tup>)
        return PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex<Index + 1>(i);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> indexs = {0, 3, 8, 2, 1};
    for (size_t &i : indexs)
    {
        PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex(i);
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of the real code. The real code is a formatter for tuples. I am trying to have a way of specifying the order it is printed in, so I have it store the index in the tuple and the formatter (input_formats) and then later I go through them calling `OutputInputFormat`.

https://pastebin.com/tvc13dX2

Comment: Template parameters can't be at runtime. That's how they work. What you've got now is basically the way to do it - you have to use templates to build up code to check the runtime value and then call the template with the right parameter (at compile-time).

Comment: std::tuples (and std::pair) are also a kind of compile time helpers you would not often see in (non-library) code. In non-library code just declare your own structs. So can you explain what the real problem you are trying to solve is? The way it is stated now it seems more like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array of function pointers to operate `tuple` elements corresponding to different static indexes, and then invoke the corresponding functions through the runtime index

```
using tup = std::tuple<int, std::string, double, int>;

void PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex(size_t i)
{
  constexpr auto func_ptrs = []<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{
      +[] {
        std::cout << "\"" << std::tuple_element_t<Is, tup>() << "\"\n";
      }...
    };
  }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<tup>>{});
  
  if (i < func_ptrs.size())
    func_ptrs[i]();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YbfbeT1M8)

Comment: What about making `func_ptrs` be `static` (or move it outside of `PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex()`) so it is created only 1 time instead of every time `PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex()` is called?

Comment: Here's a version where the `tuple` is supplied to the function: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c31xYWf83)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to 康桓瑋's very nice [constant time lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955593/7582247).

My version is similar to a `switch`-like construct:

```cpp
switch(idx) {
case 0: print std::tuple_element_t<0, tup>; break;
case 1: print std::tuple_element_t<1, tup>; break;
case 2: print std::tuple_element_t<2, tup>; break;
case 3: print std::tuple_element_t<3, tup>; break;
//...
}
```

... which means that it's not constant time. A lookup for the last element will likely take longer than a lookup for the first element. I've opted to give the function an actual tuple as an argument instead of hardcoding one specific tuple type.

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
void PrintDefaultAtTupleIndex(const std::tuple<Ts...>&, std::size_t idx) {
    [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        (... || 
         (idx == Is && (std::cout << '"' 
                                  << std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>{} 
                                  << "\"\n", true)));
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

The fold expression "unfolds" to:

```cpp
( 0 == Is && (print_defval_for_elem<0>, true) ) ||
( 1 == Is && (print_defval_for_elem<1>, true) ) ||
( 2 == Is && (print_defval_for_elem<2>, true) ) ||
( 3 == Is && (print_defval_for_elem<3>, true) );
```

<sup>`print_defval_for_elem` is pseudo code for the actual printing line which is too long to make readable.</sup>

A successful streaming to `std::cout` leaves `std::cout` in a good state which means that it will evaluate to `true` in a boolean context, but I don't care about if it was successful or not and use the comma operator to discard the result and replace it with `true`. The result is that if `idx == Is`, it will print the default value for the type and short-circuit/stop evaluating the expression. It's similar to a `break` in a `switch`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MxTE1aEY4)